# Inequality in composing two permutations

Tags: inequality, finite-groups, permutations, combinations

This is a follow up question from this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1912584/bound-of-number-of-cycles-in-composing-two-permutations). Given two permutations $g$ and $g'$ of $\{1,...,n\}$, we denote by $\mathrm{Cycle}(g)$ the set of cycles in $g$, and denote by $n_c$ the number of digits in a cycle $c\in\mathrm{Cycle}(g)$. When we compose $g$ and $g'$, I wonder if the following inequality holds true in general:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{c\in \mathrm{Cycle}(g\circ g')}\frac{1-n_c^2}{n_c}\geq \sum_{c\in \mathrm{Cycle}(g)}\frac{1-n_c^2}{n_c}+\sum_{c\in \mathrm{Cycle}(g')}\frac{1-n_c^2}{n_c}
\end{equation}

$\frac{1-n_c^2}{n_c}=(1-n_c)\left(\frac{1+n_c}{n_c}\right)$. If there was no factor of $\left(\frac{1+n_c}{n_c}\right)$ in each term, the above inequality would be just the triangle inequality of Cayley weight.

I did a few experiments in which I didn't find any counter-example of the above inequality. But could anyone help me to prove/disprove this inequality in general?